# Django how to update querysets' jsonfield based on current value

Tags: django, django-models

According to django docs, queryset could be updated with F expression as

```
qs.update(stories_filed=F('stories_filed')+1)
```

How can we use the F expression on nested jsonfield?

Assuming I have a jsonfield as `extra_data = models.JSONField(default=dict)`, and I use `extra_data['logs']` to record actions in this model, which means `extra_data['logs'] = ['log1', 'log2']` What is required is something like

```
qs.update(extra_data__logs=F('extra_data__logs').append('some logs'))
```

Is there any way to update jsonfield like above?